# Bootstrap Layout Too Wide on Smart Phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm trying to come up with an HTML/CSS layout for mobile devices. (It will likely be a separate website just for mobile devices, but I may be able to get away using a responsive site for both.)

I'm using Bootstrap, and found a layout that I'm implementing. You can see it at http://softcircuits.com/MediCorp/Menus.htm.

The problem is, when I load this page on my Android device (LG G2), the page is slightly wider than my display. So I can view the right side of the page only by scrolling horizontally.

I tried changing all of the **container** references to instead use **container-fluid** but it made no difference.

Does anyone know how I can make this page fit my device?

**UPDATE:**

Steven Wave has been helpful. He suggested some CSS to allow word wrapping. But A) the table still doesn't fit on my LG G2 (1080 x 1920 display), and B) why on Earth is word wrapping prevented by Bootstrap in the first place? Isn't Bootstrap responsive designed to work on cell phones?

Comment: use col-sm-* and col-xs-* classes to position the dom elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so here my last suggetion :)

Overrule again the default bootstrap attributes like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
   .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>th, 
   .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>td, 
   .table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>td {
        word-break: break-word;
   }
}
```

and you will be able to achieve your goal.
But i think this is a confusing table and it is not very readable. Because of this bootstrap decided to use the horizontal scrolling behavior. Just for readability.

[image]

Update Scaling:
There a several ways you can "scale".

1. CSS 3 transform: scale(x,y)
2. With several plugins to manipulate fontsizes eg.
3. Media Queries

In your case i would decide to use `Media Queries` so i manipulated your updated site with the `Developer Tools`

First i added `ÌD's` to the tables so i can easely overrule bootstrap and dont care about specificity.

```
<div class="container table-responsive">
    <p>....</p>
    <table class="table" id="tableA">....</table>
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="tableB">....</table>
</div>
```

Then i created specific media queries for the points where the table widths become bigger then the viewport.

```
    @media (max-width: "500px") {

        #tableB td, #tableB th {
            padding: 5px 2px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: "400px") {            
        .container {
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }

        #tableB td, #tableB th {
            padding: 5px 2px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: "450px") {
        #tableA td {
            padding: 5px 2px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: "350px") {
        #tableA td {
            padding: 5px 1px;
            font-size: 10px;
        }
    }
```

In this scenario it's all about space so i reduced the `.container` attributes as well go get more space.

Now you can resize your site down to 290px (whitch is absolutely ok - most mobile devices are now coverd) and the tables fit to the with.

275px!!

[image]

The tabel headers of the second table are very close together but it's also ok i think.

290px!!

[image]

Ok know the font-size is smal but there is also the posibility the scale the content trough the smartphone.

Hope that will help!

Comment: Yes, I agree that is not ideal. Can you say anything about scaling? In one case, I turned my phone to horizontal orientation and the text seemed like it got bigger such that it was still too wide by the same amount. Is there any way to scale it smaller to fit?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'm still a little puzzled why some of this wasn't already made to accommodate smart phones. It will be a bit until I can go through all this information, but it appears you have certainly answered the question. Thanks again.

Comment: I finally got time to work through all your suggestions. I can see that I might just have too much content for phones. One issue I'm having: Your scaling code doesn't seem to work on my LG G2, with 1080 x 1920 display. It appears it's because your @media declarations start at a max-width of 500, and my phone isn't that small. Yet, the tables are still too wide to fit in my phone. Did I miss something stupid? Have you dealt with stuff like this on your own? Are you available for a little bit of consulting work with me? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, 1st you can change the media query to what you want and 2nd im pretty shure that your phone dosn't have a `browser-size`of 1080 * 1920. You can check that on [THIS PAGE](http://whatsmy.browsersize.com/) just open it with your phone

Comment: Ha, it says my screen size is 360x592, but my browser size is 980x1392! I'll have to think about that one. At any rate, I think this does highlight the limitations of trying to manually scale font sizes this way. You can tweak it until it looks good on your phone, but it's not always a good indicator of how it will look on other devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes up with your table! You can resolve this with adding the `table-responsive` attribute to your 'container' div which includes both tables!!

UPDATE:

```
<div class="container table-responsive">
    <p>....</p>
    <table class="table">....</table>
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">....</table>
</div>
```

A better way is to wrapp only the tables and not the hole content!

Have a look at the [bootsrap DOCUMENTATION](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)

UPDATE:

Here the final bootstrap specific solution:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>....</p>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">....</table>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">....</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will avoid the empty space at the second table. In general the bootstrap responsive table is fluid as long as the `td` content does not fill the space. When the content is longer then the horicontal scrolling for the table appears. This is the typical behavior!

If you realy DON'T want that you should go a nother way! Thera are plenty of diffrent solutions for responsive tables out there like [THIS](http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/)

Maybe you find one that fitts your needs!

Comment: Thanks, but when I add the **table-responsive** class to this div, my tables now are much wider, taking as much room as needed so that cell contents do not wrap. Did I miss something?

Comment: I posted the modified version at http://www.softcircuits.com/MediCorp/Menus2.htm.

Comment: Is getting Bootstrap to adjust to mobile devices really that complicated? I thought that was the whole idea. Using your second code, the divs do in fact fit perfectly within my display. But the tables simply scroll horizontally within the divs, as they are still too wide. I know my table text is too wide, but why can't it just word wrap.

Comment: I made alot of responsive websites and i think bootstrap is awesome. The BS table concept make sense because normally you want to give users the possibility to read the table content on mobile devices as well! Of Course there are better solutions for tables with different approaches to display the content. You might choose one that fit your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by giving users the possibility to read the table content on mobile devices as well. In this case, I am only concerned with a mobile device, which I don't seem able to make my table fit. One of my columns can word wrap more and then fit. Is that unreasonable?

Answer (score 2):

Overrule the bootsrap attributes from `white-space: nowrap;` to `normal`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
   .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>th, 
   .table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>th, 
   .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>th, 
   .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>td, 
   .table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>td,  
   .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>td {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

So the tables fit down to 430px. For all smaler devices the scrolling appears.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to get to this until now. I believe the css above should be enclosed in curly braces? I see that this now allows word wrapping. But it still doesn't fit on my 1080x1920 LG G2, which has a screen larger than some.

Comment: I've opened a bounty on this question, and added a comment about what kind of information I'm looking for. I invite you to participate further. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: sorry i just copied the values from the dev tools so thats why the braces where missed!

Answer (score 0):

for positioning example :

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-6">
column 1 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
column 2 
</div>
</div>
```

can use this for tr and td also

Comment: This is not the way `resoponsive tables` in bootsrap should be used! [DOCUMENTATION](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution that change N-columns table to list of properties for screen that `width` is less than 1000px:

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        #userManageTable {
            margin-top: 16px;
        }

        #userManageTable, #userManageTable thead, #userManageTable tbody, 
        #userManageTable th, #userManageTable td, #userManageTable tr {
            display: block;
        }

        /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */

        #userManageTable thead tr {
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        #userManageTable tbody tr {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td {
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%;
            height: 49px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #userManageTable tfoot {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #userManageTable tfoot td {
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            position: relative;
            height: 49px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td:before {
            /* Now like a table header */
            position: absolute;
            /* Top/left values mimic padding */
            top: 6px;
            left: 6px;
            width: 45%;
            padding-right: 10px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        /*
        Label the data
        */

        #userManageTable tbody td:nth-of-type(1):before {
            content: "Imię";
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td:nth-of-type(2):before {
            content: "Nazwisko";
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td:nth-of-type(3):before {
            content: "Login";
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td:nth-of-type(4):before {
            content: "Aktywność";
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td:nth-of-type(5):before {
            content: "";
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td:nth-of-type(6):before {
            content: "";
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td:nth-of-type(7):before {
            content: "";
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td:nth-of-type(8):before {
            content: "";
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td:nth-of-type(9):before {
            content: "";
        }

        #userManageTable tbody td:nth-of-type(10):before {
            content: "";
        }
    }
</style>
```

It works with default Bootstrap v.3 CSS. 
Just give it  `id = "userManageTable"`.